# How to prevent my mana value from going negative

Tags: javascript, html

So when I use my skill it takes 10 mana from mana total then adds 50 to cookie total but if I use the skill again it keeps taking mana. i have it set so cookies does not increase but my mana keeps going down. how do i prevent values from going negative.

I haven't tried much not sure how to prevent it

This is my Javascript code:

```
function Bigclick() {
        if (ManaPoints >= 10)
        if (rebirths >=1)    
        cookies = cookies + 50
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints - 10;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
        checkCursor()
}
```

I expect If im below 10 mana or at 0 mana for the function to not do anything. but the actual output the Mana keeps going down http://prntscr.com/ns2d0m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `if`s only works for `cookies = cookies + 50`. You need to open a block and wrap all calculations that depends on those conditions, e.g.:

```
function Bigclick() {
    if (ManaPoints >= 10 && rebirths >=1) {
        cookies = cookies + 50
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints - 10;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
    }
    checkCursor()
}
```

Not sure if the code above is exactly what you need, it is just an example.

Another example of how your conditions were woring initially:

```js
var truthy = false;

if (truthy)
if (!!truthy)
console.log("truthy");
console.log("not truthy");
```

UPDATE:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("use-mana"),
    manaQty = document.getElementById("mana-qty");
    
const manaCost = 10;
    
button.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
  let qty = Number(manaQty.innerText);
  
  if (qty >= manaCost)
  {
    qty-= manaCost;
    manaQty.innerText = qty;
  }
  else 
  {
    window.alert("Not enough mana!");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="mana-qty">29</div>
<button id="use-mana">Use Mana</button>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. is there a easier way to make it so variables cant go negative tho? like if Manapoints -10>=0

Comment: You can't add the constraint to the variable itself. All you can do is not subtract from it if doing so would make it negative. I think DontVoteMeDown's answer is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Generally - if you want to avoid a number becoming negative after subtraction - you have to check if it would be smaller than 0 if you subtract a specific value. If it does make it zero, if it doesn't subtract the desired amount.

```
if (ManaPoints - 10 < 0) {
  ManaPoints = 0;
} else {
  ManaPoints -= 10;
}
```